# Same object name extend interface typescript

Tags: typescript

```js
export interface example {
  book:{
    first:number;
    second:string;
  }
}

interface table extends example{
  book:{
    third:null
  }
}
```

Is it possible to extend same object in typescript ? in some case I only want to use example case without book third

Comment: Example without book third is example right. I did not understand what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just make `third` an optional property in the `example` interface?

```
export interface example {
  book:{
    first:number;
    second:string;
    third?: null;
  }
}
```

If you really need to extend `example` interface, you have to make the types compatible, ie the extended `book` needs at least all the properties, the base interface has ...

```
export interface example {
  book:{
    first:number;
    second:string;
  }
}

interface table extends example{
  book:{
    first: number;
    second: string;
    third:null
  }
}
```